# Using ng-hide or ng-show on select box option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

Is it possible to hide select box options using the ng-hide directive?

http://jsfiddle.net/cr4UB/

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Controller">
    <select ng-model="myDropDown">
          <option value="one">One</option>
          <option value="two" ng-hide="myDropDown=='one'">Two</option>
          <option value="three">Three</option>
    </select>

    {{myDropDown}}
</div>
```

Comment: What version of AngularJS are you using, and are you locked into that version?

Comment: Using version 1.2.  Thanks Chandermani and Andre, both were good answers, but Chandermani's solution is the more simple path for what I'm after. Upvotes for all though :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

AngularJS 1.1.5 has a directive `ng-if` which can work for you. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/bgsVw/

Comment: but what happens when you select option two, it seems to not appear in the dropdown

Comment: `ng-if` shows the content if the condition is evaluated to true. You need to write condition accordingly.

Comment: @DavidChase i don't know, the context of when to hide or not, so i just took original example and replaced ng-hide with ng-if. ng-hide and ng-show only add some class to html.Whereas ng-if manipulates the DOM.

Comment: i understand your logic, but doesnt your solution pose another problem?

Comment: I did not get the problem you are mentioning.

Comment: @DavidChase You would just need to change the `ng-if` condition to `ng-if="myDropDown!='one'"` to fulfill OP's example using Chandermani's solution.

Comment: `ng-if` did the trick. If you use `ng-hide` or `ng-show`.. it was working fine on chrome.. but IE was still displaying the option even if the condition was truthy to hide it.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get it to work using `ng-hide` to check the value of your `ng-model` (likely some race-condition with reading/writing to the same model at once), however, I did come up with a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/cr4UB/2/) of the functionality you're after:

#### View markup

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Controller">
    <select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="o for o in options"></select>

    {{selectedOption}}
</div>
```

#### Controller

```
function Controller ($scope) {
    var initialOptions = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];

    $scope.options = initialOptions;
    $scope.selectedOption = $scope.options[2]; // pick "Three" by default

    $scope.$watch('selectedOption', function( val ) {
        if( val === 'One' ) {
            $scope.options = ['One', 'Three'];
        } else {
            $scope.options = initialOptions;
        }
    });
}
```